# Angular directive does not load the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularJS and I am trying to create a small website to learn how it works. My web has three elements:

- A menu bar
- A container with a little presentation
- A modal window

This is the link to the controller with these three elements:

https://github.com/ardiadrianadri/angular-bootstrap/blob/master/WebContent/js/controllerMainFrame.js

And this is the link to the main directory of my code:

https://github.com/ardiadrianadri/angular-bootstrap

The problem is that the two first elements works fine but the third one does not. In fact, the template of the modal window is never loaded in the HTML code.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Your directive is super simple, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with that part of your code.

Comment: Post your code html and js

Comment: Look inside chrome devtools network tab to see if the browser fetches the file errorMessage.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo: **tempalteUrl** instead of **templateUrl**

```
function errorModal(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'template/errorMessage.html'
    };
}
```

The reason why angular.js not throwing any error is because when declaring a directive you just pass an object with parameters. angular doesn't even look at properties it don't familiar with (like: *tempalteUrl*) so from angular's perspective your directive is just `{restrict: 'E'}` which sadly is equals to nothing.